# Resolving Binary Links in RTF | OUT of the BOX

Tags: 2013-sp1, dynamic-linking, rtf, binary

I need to resolve Binary Links (Dynamically) from RTF field of a Component. I don't use DWT TBB in my Template and rendering output using C# or Razor TBBs. I place OOB "default finish actions" TBB at the bottom inside Template, which contains OOB "Link Resolver" TBB in it.

With the above setup, the Binary Links from RTF are being rendered as `<tridion:ComponentLink>`, but it doesn't serve my purpose. In my understanding, For Binary Links I need to render a server side tag `<tridion:BinaryLink>` by templating code. which are then resolved at server side.

So to do that, I am catching the Multimedia Links from RTF in templating code and replacing them with  (with required parameters). And it works fine as expected.

My Question is, Is this the right way to replace the links in templating code? Or is there a better or OOB solution for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, when you create component links in the RTF field, Tridion does not generates the binary link.

You may refer the [Process Download Links in Output](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/process-download-links.aspx) extension for this purpose.

This was written for SDL Tridion 2011, but hopefully may work for SDL Tridion 2013 as well.

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, I will have a look on the TBB. I guess it does the same thing, replacing the RTF binary links.

Comment: I thought the Add Binaries part of the Default Finish Actions TBB generates binary links and add Multimedia Components to the package (for DWT rendering). Or are you referring to the Razor Mediator?